# Range Gating for FMCW Radars

Tags: discrete-signals, radar

I have a question regarding on how to select a particular range of interest for the dechirp-on-receive FMCW radar for application within Synthetic Aperture Radar signal processing. If RX01 is the minimum range and RX03 is the maximum range of interest, where should I start sampling and stop sampling based on the timing diagram below?

[image: FMCW Timing relationship diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the samples equal to IF03 always. In other words, you want to ignore the overlapping part of signal from the previous sweep. Hope that answers you question.

Comment: Just to clarify, if we are looking at the bottom figure and first sweep, essentially I should only sample from the yellow dotted line to the purple dotted line?

Comment: You should go from purple to red for the first sweep.